# iPod touch 3rd generation takes a very long time to send iMessages

Tags: ipod-touch, messages

My iPod touch 3rd generation takes a very long time to send iMessages. I recently sent a iMessage to my friend, it took about three hours to send. What's going on and how can I fix it? I did try turning my iPod off and back on again.

Comment: It's probably an issue with your internet connectivity.

Comment: texts normally mean SMS messages - do you really mean that as a iPod touch does not connect to phone networks and so can't and SMS

Comment: What version of iOS are you running?